# How to bind Array data to DataGrid and realize data update?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I want to bind the Array to a 4-column DataGrid and update the data. Is this possible?

If it can't be achieved, how do I need to modify it?

For automatic updates, it seems that we can bind to some collection of objects with editable values is to define a class for the item. But i don't know how to do it.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    int X=18;   
    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      int[] arr = new int[] { 61, 61, 61, 61, 61, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 18, 23, 65, 41, 22, 91, 64, 33, 18, 44, 63, 91, 26, 32, 61, 83, 91, 26, 32, 91, 91, 91, 91 };
      DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
      dataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
      dataGrid.ItemsSource = arr.ToList();
      for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
      {
        DataGridTemplateColumn column = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
        column.Header = "Value"+i;
        DataTemplate cellTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory textBlock = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBlock));
        textBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("."));
        cellTemplate.VisualTree = textBlock;
        column.CellTemplate = cellTemplate;

        DataTemplate cellEditingTemplate = new DataTemplate();
        FrameworkElementFactory textBox = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(TextBox));
        textBox.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("."));
        cellEditingTemplate.VisualTree = textBox;
        column.CellEditingTemplate = cellEditingTemplate;

        dataGrid.Columns.Add(column);
      }
      canvas.Children.Add(dataGrid);
      Canvas.SetLeft(dataGrid, X);
    }
  }
```

The result:

[image]

I want a result like this：

61, 61, 61, 61, 61,

20, 30, 40, 50, 100,

200, 300, 400, 500, 0,

0, 0, 0, 0, 18,

Comment: You could create a class with Properties `Value1` to `value4` and have an array of this class instead of an array of int.

Comment: Can it be achieved through an array? I have seen this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1905139c-d3e6-4a45-8716-2e52b6d4b77f/binding-a-datagrid-to-a-1d-array?forum=wpf), but i don't know how to create method `GetItems(arr);`. I don't know how to use Array and class collection together

Comment: *"I want to bind the Array to a 4-column DataGrid"* - Your your sketched result implies a 5 column table.

Comment: array doesn't fulfill listed requirements. accept that fact and use a different data structure. DataTable with integere columns should work just fine

Comment: Thank you all, I would also like to know the complete implementation of the second method in the [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1905139c-d3e6-4a45-8716-2e52b6d4b77f/binding-a-datagrid-to-a-1d-array?forum=wpf) I posted above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it using arrays only. Note, that `ItemsControl.ItemsSource` is of type `IEnumerable`: you can assign the array directly to this property.
The `ToList()` call is redundant here.
Also use a `DataGridTextColumn` instead of the `DataGridTemplateColumn` to eliminate the modification of the cell templates, only to add a `TextBlock`.

`DataGrid` treats each item of its `IEnumerable` source collection as a row. This is why your table looks that way: each number is written into a new row. This is repeated for each column.

This means, you must change your data structure to adapt to the each-item-to-a-row rule. Because you have five columns, you have to structure your array to provide elements of 5-tuples (quintuple) - each quintuple element to a row.
You can achieve this by using a jagged array i.e. array of arrays.

Then when configuring the `DataGrid.Columns`, you have to use the binding indexer in order to extract the column's value from the array (row data).

> "For automatic updates [...]"

You must know that there is no "automatic update" when using an array. If you want to modify the array while the application is running (dynamic data) you must use an `ObservableCollection<int[]>` instead of the `int[][]` jagged array.

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
  public MainWindow()
  {
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += OnLoaded;
  }

  private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
    int[][] numbers = 
    { 
      new[] { 61, 61, 61, 61, 61 }, 
      new[] { 20, 30, 40, 50, 100 },
      new[] { 200, 300, 400, 500, 0 } 
    };
        
    this.NumbersDataGrid.ItemsSource = numbers;
 }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```xml
<Window>
    <DataGrid x:Name="NumbersDataGrid"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value1"
                          Binding="{Binding [0]}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value2"
                          Binding="{Binding [1]}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value3"
                          Binding="{Binding [2]}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value4"
                          Binding="{Binding [3]}" />
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Value4"
                          Binding="{Binding [4]}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
  </DataGrid>
</Window>
```